# ZeroBrane Studio won't run? (MacOS)

Tags: macos, lua, zerobrane

It used to run just fine, but now when I run it, it simply sits on my bottom tray with no active window open.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it (homebrew).
I haven't tried previous versions since this one (1.90) seems to have worked fine for me before.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Edit: using Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: What exact version of macOS are you running it on? Have you recently upgraded macOS?

Comment: Catalina 10.15.6, yes recently updated (I'm rather a Mac noob, sorry!). I didn't consider the update possibly breaking it, that's a good point. What can I do to verify it?

Comment: I'd try opening the app and going to `Contents/ZeroBraneStudio` folder and then running `bin/lua src/main.lua` from the command line. I wonder if there is going to be an error message with some additional information. I'm not sure what's packaged in homebrew, but could you try installing it from the [project website](https://studio.zerobrane.com/) (the download page includes link to .dmg file)?

Comment: There is one more thing to try. Can you remove the session configuration file to see if it may be triggering this issue (https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#session-configuration)? It may be useful to save a copy first, as I'd like to review it if removing it indeed fixes the issue.

Comment: It seems that zerobrane doesn't support Catalina? So I'll try out Android Studio (which is supposed to have a plugin for Lua). Thank you for all the help though!

Comment: ZeroBrane Studio (1.90) does support Catalina for sure and has been tested on it (including 10.15.6).

Comment: Strange. I suggested that because an other member of my team described the same problem after he upgraded to Catalina. I'll try your other solutions and report back!

Comment: Have you had a chance to try suggestion to remove the session file to see if the IDE launches?

Comment: Sorry for the long interval between updates. Indeed removing the session configuration file allows zerobrane to run. Thank you!

Comment: The problem seem to occur every now and then, in which case I remove the session configuration file to solve it. I'll see where I can submit a bug report on it, and hopefully it'll be solved.

Comment: The issue is being discussed in this ticket: https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/1085